# Serve static version of a WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, static, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site which I would like to do the following with:

- Compile and serve the homepage as a **static** HTML page **only**.
- Leave all other pages untouched

The Simply Static plugin looks great but this makes a static version of the ***entire*** website.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/

I only need to serve the homepage as a flattened, static page.

Advice would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile and serve"?  By default, PHP (a server side script), does just that... compiles the code and serves the HTML back to the requester.  Do you mean that you want to physically write out the home page as static HTML and have WordPress run the rest of the site?